# How to set chart size in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an activity that has a LinearLayout and I put my chart into this:

```
...
mChart = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer, 0.3f);
graphActivityLayout.addView(mChart, 1);
```

This fills up my whole layout. How can I specify the dimensions of the chart? I haven't found any ways to do it.

My `onResume` method check if the mChart is null and if not, then calls repaint on it, otherwise sets up the chart data and does the above snippet. Nothing that is related to my question.

Comment: post your onResume() method..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the chart view has layout dimensions set to "FILL_PARENT" as default. This in general eats up all the space of a linear layout and hides the other views in the same layout.
If you have just one other view in the layout (I guess at position 0 from your code snippet), which has the layout-width/height set to "WRAP_CONTENT", it is sufficient to set an arbitrary non zero weight for the chart view. This tells the linear layout to use the remaining space, rather than to use all space:

```
graphActivityLayout.addView(mChart, 1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mChart.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the chart is not shown only the other things (button, etc) that were previously not there.

Comment: So maybe the "other things", have fill_parent as height (if its a vertical LinearLayout)?

Answer (score 0):

I added a new LinearLayout that wraps my chart and I set its height to the desired one.